# In R, how can I find rows with any values included in a column

Tags: r

I have two dataframe:
df1: Names of staff in my organization.
df2: Names of staff in 10 different organizations

I would like to find people listed in df1 from df2. In particular, I would like to make an additional variable showing whether the names in df2 is overlapped with names in df1 (yes:1, no:0)

How should I code this?
Thanks

Comment: You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Please show the code you have tried or state what you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

Use `data.table` to check for matches between `df1` and `df2` on `staff_names` column.

```r
library(data.table)
```

**Manually create data tables**

```
df1 <- data.table(staff_names = c("John Appleseed", "Daniel Lewis", "Todd Smith"))
df2 <- data.table(staff_names = c("John Appleseed", "Greg Scott", "Tony Hawk"))
```

**Code:**

```
df3 <- df1[df2, on=c(staff_names="staff_names"), overlap:="1"]
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0

#>       staff_names overlap
#> 1: John Appleseed       1
#> 2:   Daniel Lewis       0
#> 3:     Todd Smith       0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>